# sql query in order to retrieve data

Tags: sql

[image]

I want to retrieve the employee name who gain smaller salary than his manager.

For example:

Employee_Lastname: WARX

Employee_Firstname : CYNTHIA

MANAGER_NANE: SMITH

Warx Cythnia has the manager with Manager_ID=7369 who is Smith John because Smith has the Employee_ID=7369. Moreover Warx's salary is smaller than Smith(1575<8900)

```
SELECT  a.Employee_LastName, a.Employee_Firstname 
FROM    EMPLOYEE a
    LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE b
        ON a.Manager_ID = b.Employee_ID AND a.Employee_Salary > b.Employee_Salary
```

Comment: Can you post any of the queries that you have tried?

Comment: This should not have been closed as not constructive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this has slight modification from your previous question,

```
SELECT  a.Employee_LastName,
        a.Employee_FirstName,
        b.Employee_LastName AS MANAGER_LASTNAME
FROM    EmpTable a
        LEFT JOIN EmpTable b
            ON a.Manager_ID = b.Employee_ID
WHERE   a.employee_salary < b.employee_salary
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
SELECT e1.employee_id, e1.lastname, e1.firstname
FROM employee e1 INNER JOIN employee e2 ON e1.manager_id = e2.employee_id
WHERE e1.employee_salary < e2.employee_salary
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Employee_Firstname
From Employee worker
INNER JOIN Employee manager ON worker.Employee_ID = manager.Manager_ID
AND worker.Employee_Salary < manager.Employee_Salary
```